# Correr comando de CMD en C#

Tags: c#, cmd

Si tengo algo asi: (no realmente lo mismo)

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C cd..";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Como puedo hacer para correr el siguiente comando:

```
cscript "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OSPP.VBS" /dstatus
```

Lo intento pegarlo en el "arguments" pero se cierra muy rapido y lo que logro ver (antes de que la pantalla se cierre, es que da error)

Comment: Ese comnado en una linea de comandos anda? nos mostras como lo escribiste en tu programa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder ver si hay algun problema podrias redefinir el `standar output` de la consola

Para eso pones en true la propiedad

[ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput?view=netframework-4.8)

y luego asignas

[Process.StandardOutput Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=netframework-4.8)

asi podras acceder a la salida

```
using (Process process = new Process())
{
     process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
     process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"cscript \"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OSPP.VBS\" /dstatus";
     process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     process.Start();

     StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput;
     string output = reader.ReadToEnd();
 }
```

y ese string lo muestras en pantalla para ver como resulto la ejecucion

Comment: No puedo ejecutar esta linea `process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"cscript \"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OSPP.VBS\" /dstatus";` creo que es por la dobles comillas

Comment: pero obtienes algun mensaje de error en la ejecucion ? porque se usa el `\"` para definir las comillas dentro del string del argumento

Comment: si, pero no navega a la ruta, si no que me muestra la ruta donde esta alojado el proyecto "....bin\Debug"

Comment: que quiere decir que no navega el proyecto? podes mostrar donde esta tu proyecto, y como haces la llamada en la pregunta, asi tenemos un escenario mas claro???

Comment: a que llamas navegar a la ruta ? esta claro que el `cmd` como es parte de un comando conocido lo ejecuta desde cualquier ruta, ahora si `cscript ` no lo es quizas debas definir la ruta de esta en el PATH del enviroment de la pc